# Resource Injection vulnerability

Tags: java, resources, fortify, esapi, server-side-attacks

Am trying to resolve a resource injection issue found in our code by Fortify Static scan. We have `updateUserInfo(User user)` method in `Service` class which makes a call to `updateUser(User user)` method on `Dao` class. `updateUser(User user)` method code has below lines of code.

```
 public void updateUser(User user) {
     Map params = new HashMap();
     params.put("id", user.getId());
     // below code makes a call to stored proc updateUser and passes params as parameters to database(ibatis config)
     getSqlMap.update("updateUser", params);
 }
```

Fortify complains that attacker can specify the value that enters at `updateUserInfo` in `Service` class and this value is used to access a system resource at the line `getSqlMap.update` call.

I am not sure how to change this code to overcome this vulnerability. Please help.

Comment: So, Fortify is complaining that the code works as designed? Are you passing SQL as a field in `User`?

Comment: @Rüdiger Herrmann, Thanks for your comment. We pass user object but Fortify complains, input is used to identify system resource directly and its a resource injection issue. Not sure how to overcome this.

Comment: To diagnose injection we need to see the input handling code.  You need to submit more code.  How are you validating?

Comment: Also, validate that none of the fields changed by that update method aren't used to construct a URL, URI, or File/Resource reference elsewhere in the application.